# Best introduction to the link between information and thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, entropy, information

I have a solid understanding of classical thermodynamics, as well as a reasonable understanding of statistical mechanics and some of the philosophical issues regarding entropy. However, I've never understood the way modern physics handles Maxwell's demon. It's all well and good to pull $k \ln 2$'s out of a hat, but I've never understood exactly what trickery is going on. I mean, I'm very comfortable both with macroscopic justifications of the 2nd law, and with microscopic justifications based off ergodicity: I assume it's possible to reach a similar level of comfort with the works of Szilard and others.

So I'm looking for text book recommendations: are there any good books out there on this topic? Ideally I'd like a book which is as rigorous as possible (or which at least cites rigorous sources). Readability would be a nice bonus :)

Comment: Your statistical mechanics textbook has to contain a chapter about the ergodic hypothesis, which is the link between statistical mechanics and thermodynamics. I think you should read that chapter again (or find a textbook that contains it). As for the "philosophy of entropy"... there is no such thing. Entropy is a well defined physical property that can be measured just as well as force can (it is, indeed, the thermodynamic equivalent of force). As to the non-existence of Maxwell's demon... that's an experimental observation that is basically equivalent to the laws of thermodynamics.

Comment: While a somewhat controversial figure and perhaps still a controversial subject, you might look at the paper linking stat mech and information theory by ET Jaynes, [Information Theory and Statistical Mechanics](http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/theory.1.pdf). Note: this is a link to download the pdf.

Comment: I should clarify, I'm interested in the link between thermodynamics and information, not in the sense of Bayesian interpretations, but in the sense of Szilard and Landuer and other's attempts to rid the world of Maxwell's demon by demonstrating that irreversible memory erasure must increase the entropy of the universe.