# Books on entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, entropy, information

What books introduce entropy in a intuitive, elementary way (at most, for a person with undergraduate physics studies)? The book should not necessarily introduce entropy in relation only to thermodynamics, but perhaps more as a stand-alone physical measurable and in a broader context (for example, information entropy).

More original question answered in such books, the better (for example, what is the entropy of a single molecule?).

Comment: University Physics by Young and Freedman. Very intuitive approach

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214316/2451

Comment: Virtually any book on statistical mechanics, e.g. Don Lemons.

Comment: An Introduction to Thermal Physics by Daniel Schroeder  https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Thermal-Physics-Daniel-Schroeder/dp/0201380277

Answer (score 3):

Entropy Demystified (The Second Law Reduced to Plain Common Sense) by Arieh Ben-Naim. Authored discussed not only the thermodynamics origin of entropy but also the same notion in the context of information theory developed by Claude Shannon.

Answer (score 0):

I have went through a Thermodynamics Course, one of the best book which had used to clear my problem is:

**Thermal Physics by " Michael Sprackling"**

it describe the entropy in terms of both "Microstate" and "Macrostate".

I have lot of doubts and which was very helpful for me